# can't install version 14.2.11 of angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular14

I am having a lot of problems running an Angular repo. As one of my steps to solve it, I am trying to install angular/cli 14.2.11 (my colleague has that version and is able to run the repo). I have tried the following:

npm uninstall -g @angular/cli

npm cache clean --force

npm install -g @angular/cli@14.2.11

Here is what I get when I do ng version:

Angular CLI: 11.2.19

Node: 14.21.3

OS: win32 x64

Angular: error

... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core

... flex-layout, forms, language-service, localize, material

... material-moment-adapter, platform-browser

... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Ivy Workspace: Yes

### Package                         Version

@angular-devkit/architect       0.1601.8

@angular-devkit/build-angular   error

@angular-devkit/core            16.1.8

@angular-devkit/schematics      16.1.8

@angular/cli                    11.2.19

@schematics/angular             16.1.8

@schematics/update              0.1102.19

rxjs                            7.8.1

typescript                      error

I mentioned that I was having lots of issues. I downgraded my node to the version my colleague is using. I have been trying to correct the build-angular and typescript errors but they keep popping up (yes, I have tried npm install -g @angular-devkit/build-angular). I don't know why my CLI is on 11.2.19 and my @angular/core and a few other things are on 16.1.8. So I want to try to get through this one step at a time. If anyone can help me get Angular 14 on here I would appreciate it.

Comment: can you share your packagejson ?